# Why is the responisve menu not working properly?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I created A reponsive menu. I work with css `@media screen` like you can see on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xftgky3e/). Everything is working fine except one thing. Sometimes when you change between a small and a big menu the menu content isn't displayed. Take a look at the Jsfiddle and resize the width of the output window. Like I told it happens sometimes so reload the page sometimes if it don't happen the first time.

the class `menu` contains the menu content. The small menu has a `display` none (it slides down on a button click) and the big menu works with `display` inline-block.

This only happens when you change between a small and en big menu. From big to small works fine.

Can somebody help me solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you toggle the menu up, the slide up puts a display none on the menu when it's done. After your menu slides up it's hidden. When you go back to being big, it'll keep the display: none from the JS and so it doesn't show.

One way to fix this is to force it to be visible when big all the time

```
@media screen and (min-width: 550px){ /*big menu*/
    .menu{
        display:inline-block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope that is not working, the content still disappears sometimes. Where is that !important for?

Comment: @Vinc199789 line 45 of your fiddle CSS change the `display:inline-block;` to `display:inline-block !important;` the menu div after to click to hide it gets a `style="display: none" and when you make the menu large again it doesn't drop that. So you have to override the inline display:none with the !important flag. I mean you could also fix your JS so that the display none is dropped when you resize it, but I think this is an easier solution.

Comment: !important overrides all other propertys set so its forcing it to stay like that. Here is a link to important: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules

Comment: Yes that works. I pasted the !important at the wrong place. Thanks for helping and this lesson about !important

Answer (score 1):

That issue is maybe caused by the toggle logic using strings.

In your javascript, you can try a more intuitive code like so:

```
$('nav').on('click','.dropdown',function(){
    if($('.menu').css('display')=='none'){
        $('.menu').slideDown();
    }else{
        $('.menu').slideUp();
    }
});
```

It should make your script less buggy.

Comment: Question: Why did you choose this over a toggleClass('test'') where test has `display: none`  ?

Comment: using `toggle()` is not an option for his case since he wants the sliding up and down animation instead of just appearing and disappearing.